# Using React Navigation with Apollo's useQuery

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, apollo, hasura, react-apollo-hooks

I have a screen where I fetch some data from Hasura. I am using something like this:

```
// screen1.js
const {data} = useQuery(MY_QUERY)
```

In `screen1.js` I have a button that navigates to `screen2.js`. And in `screen2.js` I have some mutation that changes the data fetched in `screen1.js`. When I change this data and execute the mutation, I navigate back to `screen1.js`. I want the data in `screen1.js` to be updated accordingly.

I have tried several solutions like this (as suggested in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#usequery)):

```
const {data} = useQuery(MY_QUERY, {fetchPolicy: "network-only", pollInterval: 500})
```

But this does not work. I can't make my query a subscription because my query calls a custom action from Hasura, and I believe they only support queries and mutations.

I think a solution would be to re-render `screen1.js` when I navigate there, but I don't know if this is the optimal solution.

Comment: Have you considered or attempted using Optimstic UI when running the mutation on screen2? See: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/optimistic-ui/

Comment: @avimoondra Thanks! Didn't know about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this as your default options:

```
const defaultOptions = {
  watchQuery: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'ignore'
  },
  query: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
    errorPolicy: 'all'
  }
}
```

It should be used on something like this, depending on how you're setting up Apollo:

```
    this.client = new ApolloClient({
      link: concat(authMiddleware, link),
      cache: new InMemoryCache(),
      defaultOptions
    })
```

Comment: This also works, but I liked the most the Optimist UI pattern.